# Is it possible to undo changes in code view after saving the file in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am hoping that I am simply missing a configuration change, but I cannot seem to figure out why I lose my undo buffer in SharePoint Designer 2010 after i save a file.

I am accustomed to Visual Studio where i can make changes, save, and if the changes were incorrect, immediately ctrl-z to undo them.  This doesnt seem to be the case in SharePoint Designer 2010.  Once i hit save, i cannot undo...

Is there a configuration setting or other setting that i am missing or have configured incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those hit or miss things in SharePoint Designer, regardless the version. Generally it will work, but sometimes it doesn't.

It would be lovely if Microsoft supported the product well enough to fix this sort of thing.